# Load data from Cassandra

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, bigdata

I am using Cassandra 1.2.12 , i want to load data from cassandra using Java code, but i am forced to use limit in the query.

**Using DataStax API to fetch data from Cassandra.**

Lets assume `keyspace as 'k'` and `columnfamily as 'c'`, read data from c on some condition which results in 10 million records, since i was getting `time-out exception` i limited it to 10000, and `i know that i cant limit like 10001 to 20000....` and i want to load full 10 million records, How can i solve this problem.?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking about is called pagination, and you'll have to write queries with `WHERE key > [some_value]` to set your starting boundary for each slice you want to return.  To get the correct value to use, you'll need to look at the last row returned by the previous slice.

If you're not dealing with numbers, you can use a function `token()` to do a range check, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE token(name) > token('bob')
```

`token()` also may be required if you're paging by your partition key, which usually disallows slicing queries.  For example (adapted from [Datastax documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html)):

```
CREATE TABLE c (
  k int PRIMARY KEY,
  v1 int,
  v2 int
);

SELECT * FROM c WHERE token(k) > token(42);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading all of data from Cassandra is not a good option. With Kundera(supports datastax java driver), i know can set maxResults to Integer.MAX_VALUE, which would exclude LIMIT keyword while retrieving the data.

As Daniel said, probably what you are looking for is "pagination", use token() function for this and handle number of records per page pro grammatically. IMHO, high level apis should take care such things like of applying token implicitly in case of pagination required.

HTH,
-Vivek